# How to select the regularization parameter between two losses?

Tags: machine-learning, regularization, tensorflow, inverse-problem

In deep learning, the total loss commonly consists of a task-specific loss and a weight regularized loss:

```
loss = loss_specific + lambda * reg_loss
```

In my case (set `lambda=1.0`), I have the following observations. The `loss_specific` decreases at a faster speed than the `reg_loss`, for example:

```
step 1: loss_specific=0.77, reg_loss=1.9033
step 100: loss_specific=0.50, reg_loss=1.8997
step 200: loss_specific=0.30, reg_loss=1.8930
step 300: loss_specific=0.20, reg_loss=1.8920
```

Then, is this case related to the selection of `lambda`? In general, the `lambda` may be manually selected from `{1.0, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, ...}`. Is this the principle to select this parameter? or use the n-fold cross-validation?

To my limited knowledge of regularization, the `lambda` seems to have specific physical meaning in inverse problems, such as image denoising, image restoration or compressed sensing, which may correspond to the noise levels or some others. But I'm not sure.